# Residue of the following variant of Dirichlet function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, dirichlet-series

I am working with the [Piltz divisor problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function) where the number of ways in which a number $n$ can be written as a product of $k$ is of the form

$$D_{k}(x)=xP_{k}(\log x)+\Delta _{k}(x)$$

where $P_k$ is a polynomial of degree $k-1$ [defined](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.09589.pdf) as 
$$
P_{k-1}(log x) = Res_{s=1} x^{s-1} \zeta^{k}(s) s^{-1}\\
\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{s-1} + \gamma + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\gamma_k*(s-1)^k
$$
$\gamma_k$ is probably the $k^{th}$derivative of $-\Gamma(1)$ but I'm not sure about that.

I need help with finding this residue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For a definition of the numbers  $ \gamma_k $ , see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants

Comment: By the way, your sum should start at  $ k=1 $ cause  $ \gamma=\gamma_{0} $ is already present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at p.171 of this [paper](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=tm&paperid=2566&option_lang=eng) by A.F. Lavrik. You should find your answer there.